# How do I convert hex numbers to a character in c++?

Tags: c++, string, hex, memory-editing

I'm trying to convert a hex number to a character in C++.
I looked it up but I can't find an answer that works for me.

Here is my code:

```
char mod_tostring(int state, int index, int size) {
    int stringAddress = lua_tolstring(state, index, 0);
    const char* const Base = (const char* const)stringAddress;
    return Base[0];
};
```

Base[0] would return a hex number like:
0000005B

If you go here http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx and put 0000005B as the input it outputs the character "[". How would I also output [?

Comment: So you want to return the character that has the integer value of 0x5B?

Comment: Keep in mind that a char on most systems can only hold 2 hex values.

Comment: Also you don't specify which encoding you want to convert the hex into. There are multiple options: ASCII, UTF8, UTF16, UTF32

Comment: Whichever one notepad automatically uses.

Comment: Integers are the same whichever base you display them in. Do you mean that `Base[0]` is the value `0x5b` – that is, ninety-one – and you want the character `'['`? If that's what you mean, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: No. I just used [ as an example. It might return something else.

Comment: A number is a number.  "Hex" only applies to how we *print* the number as a string.  Are you asking: `how do I convert an integer into a hex string`?  Or are you asking, `how do I convert a hex string back to an integer`?

Comment: Really, I'm trying to display the character the value Base[0] holds. If that character was [, I want to view [ in a message box. Even if that character is not [, I still want to see it in the message box. I want to know how to read that character from Base[0].

Comment: @JamesGlenn `'['` is 91 is `0x5b`. They're all the same thing.

Comment: I think you just want the cast the integer to char and finish,no? I recommend you rephrase your question

Comment: You can see how this website does it http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx  I don't know how to explain it, but that's exactly what I want to do. If you put 0000005B in there it will output [.

Comment: That website takes `0x5b` *as a string*. Your function takes *integers*. Also, `lua_tolstring` returns `const char*`; by storing that in an `int`, you should be losing information, at least on a 64-bit system. It makes no sense to take the return value as an `int` and then cast it *back* to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To print a number as a character, you can either assign it to a `char` variable or cast it to a `char` type:

```
unsigned int value = 0x5B;
char c = static_cast<char>(value);
cout << "The character of 0x5B is '" << c << "` and '" << static_cast<char>(value) << "'\n";
```

You could also use `snprintf`:

```
char text_buffer[128];
unsigned int value = 0x5B;
snprintf(&text_buffer[0], sizeof(text_buffer),
         "%c\n", value);
puts(text_buffer);
```

**Example program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    unsigned int value = 0x5B;
    char c = static_cast<char>(value);
    std::cout << "The character of 0x5B is '" << c << "` and '" << static_cast<char>(value) << "'\n";

    std::cout << "\n"
              << "Paused.  Press Enter to continue.\n";
    std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./main.exe
The character of 0x5B is '[` and '['

Paused.  Press Enter to continue.
```

Comment: For some reason this is giving me FFFFFFDC, not [.

Comment: Strange.  I'm getting the output: `The character of 0x5B is '[` and '['`.  I'm compiling with g++ 5.3.0 on Cygwin on Windows 7.  See my edit.

Comment: I'm using the snprintf one.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
std::cout << "0x%02hX" << Base[0] << std::endl;
```

Output should be: 0x5B assuming Base[0] is 0000005B.

Comment: There is no way to convert it to a character?

Comment: Do you need the `std::hex` in that statement? (How does the compiler know to print in decimal versus hex)?

Comment: If Base[0] is BYTE * or unsigned char * it will print it, otherwise no.

Comment: Are you thinking of `printf` instead of `cout`?  My understanding is that `cout` doesn't have format specifier strings.

Comment: I want it to print the character [.

Comment: James, how do you expect to print "[" - I never done / seen such thing o.O

Comment: I don't want it to print 0x5B. Assuming Base[0] is 0000005B, I want it to print [. Go to this address http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx and put  0000005B in the input box. That's what I want to print.

Comment: Hmm, but your question is "How do I convert hex numbers to a character in c++?" - So that`s what I answered you. You should post the correct question. PS: Why -1 ?! I answered the question correctly!

Comment: I didn't give you a -1. If you go to http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx you can see how it converts.

Comment: The -1 is because `cout` doesn't work with format specifier strings.

Comment: @NorbertBoros:  The `printf` family uses format specifiers.  The C++ I/O streams like `std::cout` don't.  Look at your answer.  The output from your answer should be: `0%02h91`.  Your answer is not correct.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews And because I was in a rush and answered quickly, I deserve a -1 ? I don't understand you people!

Comment: You probably got downvoted because "try this" answers are not considered good answers. A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. If you want to get the rep back you lost here you can delete the answer and you'll get your points back. Keep in mind that downvotes are not personal, only an indication of an answers usefulness. It doesn't matter 'who' did it. To get more rep continue to provide answers to questions, filled with good information and code examples. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯